# How do I get a voltage on a PCIe Parallel Port?

Tags: controller, c++, pci-express, parallel-port

I'm trying to use a PCIe Parallel port from C++. ([http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Express-Profile-Parallel-PEX1PLP/dp/B004G7O2AC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004G7O2AC))

I can't seem to change the status of any of the registeres and my voltometer and LEDs don't change.

I am using `inpout32`.dll on a Windows 7 x64 bit machine. I think the dll works because it successfully runs the example program (with beeps working). I used the code from http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/.

I think there is a problem with my port number. I tried the following ports with no success:

0xCC00
0xC880
0x0378

The registers read

```
ecp? x90
ecp? x40
ecp? x15

spp? x0
spp? x7f
spp? x0
spp? xff
spp? xff
spp? xff
spp? xff
spp? xff
```

[image: Pce LPT1]

Comment: Where do 'your' beeps come from? Picture? Circuit diagram? Example code?

Comment: So why did this get  migrated? I think hardware registers are a good fit for electronics?

Comment: @Mikhail I voted to migrate because this question has to do nearly merely with computer hardware and not that much with electrical engineering or electronics design.